# Jensen's inequality applied to Liapunov's CLT condition

Tags: probability, inequality, jensen-inequality

> The Liapunov's sufficient condition to the Central Limit Theorem says that if $\exists \delta$ for whom the following expression converges to $0$ then you can apply the CLT to the sequence's standardized partial sums:
>
> $$ \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}{S_{n}}}\right)^{2+\delta}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(|X_{k}-\mu_{k}|^{2+\delta}) \to 0 \implies \frac{S_{n}-\mathbb{E}(S_{n})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}S_{n}}} \xrightarrow[]{D} \mathcal{N}(0,1)
> $$

My question is if when we choose $\delta =2$, can i apply Jensen's inequality, $\mathbb{E}(\phi(X)) \geq \phi(\mathbb{E}(X))$ when $\phi$ is a convex function, as in:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}{S_{n}}}\right)^{4}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(|X_{k}-\mu_{k}|^{4})  &=\\
 \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}{S_{n}}}\right)^{4}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}((|X_{k}-\mu_{k}|^{2})^{2}) &\geq\\
 \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}{S_{n}}}\right)^{4}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(|X_{k}-\mu_{k}|^{2})^{2} & \\ 
\end{align}

It's a fairly simple doubt. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Seems like a valid application of Jensen's inequality.